# Bootstrap 4 modal backdrop is not covering full view on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap 4.5 in my project. The modal is displaying normal on desktop. But when switched to mobile device the modal backdrop is only a part of the page. Below is my code for my modal:

```
<div class="modal fade " data-easein="expandIn" id="Modalone" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-xl" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-body text-center">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" aria-hidden="true">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
                        <img src="https://i.imgur.com/voj7Bgq.png" width="80%" height="80%">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is the css code im using for the modal:

```
.modal-dialog {
    min-height: 100% !important;
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: column !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}

.modal-body {
    background-color: transparent !important;
    height: 100% !important;
}

.close {
    color: #fff !important;
}

 ::selection {
    color: none;
    background: none;
}

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
            html,
            body,
            svg {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                min-height: 1777px;
                min-width: 1000px;
            }
}
```

This is the result i am getting:

[image: Example]

What can i do to make the backdrop fully cover in different devices?

Comment: If the modals in [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/modal/) display correctly on your device, it means the source of your bug is somewhere in your code, but you haven't posted it yet. Please provide a [mcve], emphasis on *reproducible*. If the doc modals have the same problem on your device, your best bet is to open an issue [here](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues). Until you make the bug reproducible, your question is, technically, unanswerable.

Comment: Thanks @tao for the tips. I've gone through my code by recreating my code and divide and conquer at the same time. And i was able to solve it by myself.

Answer (score 1):

The block of code that is causing this bug is in the @media part where i included the min-width and min-height. The bug is gone after i removed it.